# Process not using fonts

Tags: c#, windows, azure, process, phantomjs

I'm trying to print Chinese characters in a PDF generated by an exe process (phantomjs). However these characters end up as "?". The process is created in a Worker Role in C#.

When creating the same process manually in a cmd-window on the same virtual machine, everything works fine.

The Chinese language pack is installed, however, from the same admin account that can successfully create the PDF by hand.

In order to make sure all users see the same fonts from the language pack, I added the settings to all system users on the machine [as described here](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-hk/windows/apply-regional-language-settings-reserved-accounts#1TC=windows-7).

The proces is started from C# like this

```
Process.Start(new ProcessStartInfo
{
    UseShellExecute = true,
    FileName = "phantomjs.exe",
    Arguments = "pdf.js"
});
```

So how can it be, that my manual cmd-window process uses the Chinese fonts properly, but not the process started by C#?

Comment: Difficult to say without knowing what `phantomjs` is doing.  But generally speaking programs that aren't designed to run in a non-interactive context can't be counted on to do so.  It might be worth checking whether it will work if you configure it to run in a real user account, and in particular, a user account that has been logged on interactively at least once.

Comment: @HarryJohnston Phantomjs is a headless browser. The way I use it is to render a static html page, add content in javascript, then print to pdf or even a png screenshot. Same as using a regular browser, but not interactive. The unusual thing is that fonts are used on the server side instead of the client side.

Comment: Let me rephrase: difficult to say without looking at the particular code inside `phantomjs` that is failing.

Comment: Ah sorry :) The code run by phantomjs is unlikely to be failing. The printing is done correctly, just not the Chinese characters which are converted to question marks. Latin text is fine and also uses standard fonts. Individual Chinese characters are supposed to use the SimSun font, but they don't. When installing language packs, users get additonal Registry entries which add these fonts to the font selection pool, I think.

Comment: It's failing to render the fonts.  I don't really understand why it would need any information from the user registry to do that; fonts are not installed on a per-user basis on Windows.  But assuming for the moment that it is looking for something in the user registry, my best guess is that this is something that is added to the registry when a user first logs in interactively.  So try running it in the context of a user account that has been logged in interactively.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out wrong character encoding causes the question marks.
Everything from content input to the HTML docs and output settings have to use the correct encoding (e.g. UTF-8), then it works.